# How to move all cloudtrail logs to one centralized location

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to collect CloudTrail logs into our SIEM. The SIEM Vendor can only collect logs from S3 from a single folder but Cloudtrail creates a folder for each day. I need to create a lambda function that looks when a file is added to one of these subdirectories and moves them to the same location:

Example of what we have now:

```
Bucketname/CloudTrail/323232/ca-central/2019/06/02/files.json.gz
Bucketname/CloudTrail/323232/ca-central/2019/06/03/files.json.gz
Bucketname/CloudTrail/323232/ca-central/2019/06/04/files.json.gz
```

Example of what we want to see:

```
Bucketname/CloudTrail/323232/ca-central/files1.json.gz
Bucketname/CloudTrail/323232/ca-central/files2.json.gz
Bucketname/CloudTrail/323232/ca-central/files3.json.gz
```

I have tried looking for examples online but cannot find anything that matches.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change the prefix of the s3 bucket path by editing both the **S3 bucket policy** and the cloudtrail **Log file prefix**. To achieve this you can follow the directions at the bottom of [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/create-s3-bucket-policy-for-cloudtrail.html#specify-an-existing-bucket-for-cloudtrail-log-delivery), under "Changing a Prefix for an Existing Bucket".

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that still makes the subfolders per day ex: "/2019/06/02/" Which I'm trying to avoid

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact that each CloudTrail event file that CloudTrail sends contains the timestamp and a UUID then it is very unlikely that there will be collision hit.

Having said that, if you're willing to copy all data (without grouping days) into one folder (also consider that S3 buckets scale practically infinitely) then you can consider doing the following:

1. (a) Setting up S3 Object Level notifications on your CloudTrail bucket which will put a message into an SQS queue on every new file CloudTrail sends.
2. (b) Alternatively, you can configure an SNS Topic in the CloudTrail Trail where CloudTrail will put a message every time CloudTrail delivers a file and then connect that SNS Topic to an SQS Queue.
3. Connect the SQS Queue with a Lambda Function.
4. The Lambda Function will read the event from the SQS Queue (which will contain the new S3 file path) and simply copy (or move?) that file to the new folder.